# Transition between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have an iOS app that has a distinct screen presentation relations.

Now i've written some conditions inside the `viewDidLoad` of each screen, to be able to skip them if needed.

If the condition is met, the screen is supposed to be dismissed without showing its view, and the next screen gets loaded.

What happens is :

1. condition is met
2. screen is dismissed
3. new screen is loaded

however, the view of the previous screen blinks on the screen for a second
how can i prevent this blinking ?

This is the condition for my dismissed screen

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(self.isEditingDetails){
        [self setUserDetails:[self.userSettings getUserDetails]];
    }
    User *user = [self.userSettings getUserDetails];
    BOOL isRegistered = [user isRegistered];
    if(isRegistered || !_editingDetails){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationWithName:kNotificationShowMainScreen andObject:nil];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
        return;
    }
}
```

and this is the presentation of the new screen

```
if([[note name]isEqualToString:kNotificationShowMainScreen]){
     MainPageControllerViewController *mainScreen = (MainPageControllerViewController *)[_window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainPagerControllerViewController"];

        [_window.rootViewController presentViewController:mainScreen animated:YES completion:^{
            self.window.rootViewController = mainScreen;
        }];
}
```

Comment: I think that you should re-design your app so that the view is only presented if it is needed

Comment: there is no other way?

Comment: Not that I know of.  There is no "shouldPresentViewController" method in the view lifecycle - your app has requested a view controller be presented, so it will be presented no matter how briefly.  It should be fairly straight-forward to create a class that manages your application flow and presents the appropriate view controllers